# Metric space union proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Suppose $(A, d)$ is a metric space and let $D, E \subseteq A$ be subsets. Show that $\partial(D \cup E) \subseteq \partial(D) \cup \partial(E)$. Then, if $\overline{D} \cap \overline{E} = \emptyset$, show that $\partial(D \cup E) = \partial(D) \cup \partial(E)$.

Note: For a set $B$, $\partial B$ refers to the frontier of that set; that is, $\partial B = \overline{B} \cap \overline{B^c}$ where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$.

My attempt:

Suppose $x \in \partial(D \cup E)$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap (D \cup E) \neq \emptyset \land B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap (D \cup E)^c \neq \emptyset$. Since $B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap (D \cup E)^c \neq \emptyset$, the sets $B_0(x, \epsilon)$, $D^c$ and $E^c$ have a non-empty intersection. So $x \notin (D \cup E)^c$ and then $x \in D \land x \in E$. Hence at least one of the intersections $B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap D$ or $B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap E$ is not empty. So we get that for all $\epsilon > 0$

$$(B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap D \neq \emptyset \land B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap D^c \neq \emptyset) \lor (B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap E \neq \emptyset \land B_0(x, \epsilon) \cap E^c \neq \emptyset)$$

We may conclude that $x \in \partial(D) \cup \partial(E)$.

QED.

Is this proof correct? I am not sure how $\partial(D) \cup \partial(E) = \partial(D \cup E)$ follows if $\overline{D} \cap \overline{E} = \emptyset$. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\bar D \cap \bar E =\emptyset. $ It suffices to consider $ x \in \partial D$ and show it is in the boundary of $D \cup E$. Clearly $x$ is in the closure of that union, so we have to show it is also in the closure of $(D \cup E)^c=D^c \cap E^c$. Every ball $B(x,r)$ centered at $x$ intersects $D^c$. Moreover, since $x \in \bar D$ we infer that $x \notin \bar E$. Thus if $r$ is small enough, then $B(x,r)$ is disjoint from $E$ so
$B(x,r) \cap E^c \cap  D^c = B(x,r)   \cap  D^c \neq \emptyset. $

Comment: Forgive me for the late response. Does this automatically imply that $\partial (D \cup E) = \partial (D) \cup \partial (E)$?

Comment: Yes, it shows $\partial D \subset \partial (D \cup E)$. Similarly, $\partial E \subset \partial (D \cup E)$. Therefore $\partial D \cup \partial E \subset \partial (D \cup E)$  and you already checked the other direction.